# How to create a digital certificate by using SHA algorithm? Error: Can't access the key of the subject ('MySPC.pvk')

Tags: .net, iis, sha256, digital-certificate

I thought of to create a certificate by using SHA 256 and certify the the website which i hosted in IIS.First i tried to create certificate by using following command.

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=My SPC" -a sha256 -cy end ^
         -sky signature ^
         -ic MyCA.cer -iv MyCA.pvk ^
         -sv MySPC.pvk MySPC.cer
```

but i am getting error like

```
More?          -sky signature ^
More?          -ic MyCA.cer -iv MyCA.pvk ^
More?          -sv MySPC.pvk MySPC.cer
Error: Can't access the key of the subject ('MySPC.pvk')
Failed
```

i dont know why i am getting.Next question i am having is if evrything creates succefully where do i find certificate MySPC.cer ? next question is how to assign  this to an website hosted in IIS? can any body suggest me a solution

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault and already has an answer there. See http://serverfault.com/questions/693017/how-can-i-create-self-signed-certificate-that-is-stronger-than-sha-1.

Comment: @JamieSee thats great , i created by using that command successfully, but where do i find that certificate?

Comment: It will be located in your current working directory unless you specify a full path. If you're doing this in a Command Prompt window as you should be, your prompt should contain the current path plus a > character. Enter the `dir` command and you should see the new files in the list.

Comment: @JamieSee i installed certificate(.pfx) file  in system and then i set the binind in IIS,when i browsed in firefox it is not opening, but in IE i continued error prompt and able to see website , but it is show re icon like certificate is not from trusted certificate authority, do you know why it is coming?while importing certificate in iis it asked me password, i used password which i used while creation ,but no luck , then i imported without password, does that make any issues?

Comment: The security warning in IE is normal with a self-signed certificate. Firefox by default usually shows a warning dialog as well. You may have some security setting in it turned up. If you want your browsers to accept the certificate without generating security warnings, you'll need to generate a Certificate Signing Request and pay to have one of the public Certificate Authorities like Verisigin, Thawte, GoDaddy. etc. sign it for you. See https://www.godaddy.com/help/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-5343.

Comment: @JamieSee one more doubt by using the command provided in the link we are generating self signed certificate (CA) but which is good CA or SPC?